# Why am I getting Input mismatch exception error continously

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Servicecentre[] ab=new Servicecentre[4];
        String n,b;
        double c;
        boolean o;
        System.out.println("enter the details");
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            n=sc.nextLine();
            b=sc.nextLine();
            c=sc.nextDouble();
            sc.nextLine();
            o=sc.nextBoolean();
            ab[i]=new Servicecentre(n,b,c,o);
        }
        double ans1=findavg(ab);
        if(ans1==0)
        {
            System.out.println("No online service available");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.format("%.1f",ans1);
        }
    }
    public static double findavg(Servicecentre[] ab)
    {
        double s=0;
        double c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<ab.length;i++)
        {
            if(ab[i].getonline())
            {
                s=s+ab[i].getcharge();
                c=c+1;
            }
        }
        if(c==0)
            return 0;
        else
            return s/c;
    }
}

class Servicecentre
{
    String name;
    String branch;
    double charge;
    boolean online;
    Servicecentre(String name, String branch,double charge,boolean online)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.branch=branch;
        this.charge=charge;
        this.online=online;
    }
    String getname()
    {
        return name;
    }
    String getbranch()
    {
        return branch;
    }
    double getcharge()
    {
        return charge;
    }
    boolean getonline()
    {
        return online;
    }
}
```

This is the code of my program.
I am asked to get input of following types

- Name – String
- branch – String
- Charge – double
- Online – boolean.

and I am asked to find average of the charge only when online is true.the below are their inputs.

- TVS
- Cochin
- 2000
- false
- Bajaj
- Chennai
- 1500
- true
- TCH
- TVM
- 1000
- false
- Arrow
- Chennai
- 2500
- true

I am repeatedly getting error on that bold line and I don't know what I have done wrong .the error is like

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
at HelloCodiva.main(Main.java:19)"
```

Kindly help me with the code. I am new to java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) (if you enter your inputs one at a time, you'll notice this is the problem, i.e., it's skipping the first `nextLine` in the second iteration of your loop)

Comment: As a tangent, you don't need to import `java.lang.*`. That's implicitly imported, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you get a java.util.InputMismatchException when you accidentally feed the wrong input. Validate your input before using it, and you won't receive this error.

Ex.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That's not a number!");
        sc.next(); // this is important as it clears the input buffer
    }
    number = sc.nextInt(); // finally recieve that input
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But when I tried the above method ,my input testcase passed until 7th one,even before entering 1500,it says that is not a number.I don't know why that happens. But https://codebashers10.blogspot.com/2021/04/TCS-Xplore-CPA-24-April-2021-Shift-2-Java-Coding-Solution.html have also solved the same way I did. But I get an error like input mismatch.